# Where are my ethers? Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: error

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7eec9ecbba2ff45016d09e27bbb22ca206e6ec51386436c90ae937b563131066

Hello. That transaction was fail. It was send by an Exchange to another wallet.
The error messagge is:

```
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
```

So do that means that the funds will return to the original exchange?

I want my ETH back :-/

Comment: I already supply a ticket asking the exchange to return my funds.

Comment: Good. If it's a good exchange, you should have your money back shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exchange still has the ether in their wallet even though they may have deducted it from you balance. This means that no ether has been lost and the exchange should be able to credit your account with the missing funds again.

You may have to open a ticket for them to transfer back the amount.

The transaction ran out of gas and that means that the transaction did not change the balance on any accounts, it was reverted which means that the exchange still has the ether that it tried to send on your behalf. You can see the details of the transaction here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7eec9ecbba2ff45016d09e27bbb22ca206e6ec51386436c90ae937b563131066

Comment: Yes. The Ethers were resend with another transaction that was well executed!

Comment: Good to hear! :)